# Vulnerability Identified: It needs multifactor authentication for login

Tags: authentication, login

Vulnerability Identified: It needs multifactor authentication for login.
Is it possible to implement MFA in sitecore 7.5 application.
If yes,what are the ways we can accomplish it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But it will require a lot of effort to do it on 7.5.
I suggest you consider an upgrade to 9+ and doing MFA using IdentityServer4.

Comment: Thanks Anton, any document or tutorials which I can refer for MFA in sitecore 7.5 and for MFA using IdentityServer4.

Comment: For Sitecore 9+ with Identity Sever, there are many of them, for example https://deblokt.com/2019/10/09/07-identityserver4-mfa-totp/

For Sitecore 7.5, I don't know